# Cron Job - delete all files inside a specific folder

Tags: php, cron

I want to delete all files inside a folder called " data " with php and using Cron Job, the

Cron Job is set to run script every hour, but i'm lost what should i write in the empty

textfield and and how delete all files inside a specific folder in php??

please someone explain me and help me out...

[image]

**Fixed it:**

Placed  delete.php inside the empty field

and wrote inside delete.php the code down below:

```
<?php


define('PATH', 'folder/');

function destroy($dir) {
    $mydir = opendir($dir);
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($mydir))) {
        if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            chmod($dir.$file, 0777);
            if(is_dir($dir.$file)) {
                chdir('.');
                destroy($dir.$file.'/');
                rmdir($dir.$file) or DIE("couldn't delete $dir$file<br />");
            }
            else
                unlink($dir.$file) or DIE("couldn't delete $dir$file<br />");
        }
    }
    closedir($mydir);
}
destroy(PATH);
echo 'all done.';


?>
```

Comment: It would be easier to skip PHP and use rm -rf [path-to-data-here]/* http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rm

Comment: SHould i replace  php -f /home/a1206305/ with rm -rf [path-to-data-here]/* ?

Comment: Exactly, but replace [path-to-data-here] with the actual path. Keep the /* at the end.

Comment: let pretend that our folder url path is domain.com/folder should i place that like that -rf [ domain.com/data]/* or -rf [ /home/a1206305/data]/*

Comment: It would be like this.. `rm -rf domain.com/data/*` So, if the datafolder is in your home-catalogue, it's like `rm -rf /home/a1206305/data/*`

Comment: Okay, but what about the empty textfield? should i just leave it empty??

Comment: Either move the `-rf /home/a1206305/data/*` to that field (I guess it's for parameters and such, or just keep it empty.

Comment: I cant change the first textfield, it dont change it and when i placed: -rf /home/a1206305/data/* it said: " Path to the script cannot contain any special symbols or whitespaces "

Comment: Ah, ok. Then my solution won't work. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function from PHP that can remove a file.

https://www.php.net/unlink

And also, the example here; https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php#108940

Contains information on how you can delete files from a directory (just skip the rmdir at the bottom)

Edit: Forgot about the cron-thing. :)

If you create a file within your /home/a1206305/ called directory.php with this content:

```
<?php
    $path = "/home/a1206305/domain.com/data/";
    foreach(glob($path . "*") as $file)
    {
        if(is_file($path . $file))
            unlink($path . $file);
    }
?>
```

And then in that second field for cron, just write in directory.php

Comment: The fist example delete a file inside a folder and the second one delete the whole directory with all content, but i want delete all content inside the folder without deleting the folder itself or write every files name

Comment: My added example should do the trick, if that is the correct path in `$path`

Comment: You code didn't delete the files, but it give me a good idea which you can see in the updated description place... thanks! +1 to everyone who helped and your answer deserves accept! :)

Answer (score 12):

in cpanel go to cron job 
if you want to delete the folder including its contents:

```
rm -rf /home/user/public_html/folder
```

if you want to remove everything in this folder, but leave the folder itself:

```
rm -f /home/user/public_html/folder/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give the full file path of your php file(can include domain name as well like we run the page in browser) there and in that page write the code to delete all the files inside any folder.

Comment: Let say the full domain path is " domain.com/delete.php " where should i place it? in the empty field? should i change anything in the first field ?

Comment: you should place your file path in empty field and in the first field you can write : 

curl -s -o

Comment: I cant change the first field, but should i write url path or /home/a1206305/data/ ?

Comment: i cant say /home/a1206305/directory.php ??

Comment: you can write it like that also

Answer (score 1):

enter full path of your php file and write code to delete all files from the respective directory.
php file code:

```
$dir = 'your directory path';
foreach(glob($dir.'*.*') as $v){
unlink($v);
}
```

Comment: let say the full path to " directory.php " is: domain.com/directory.php, should i type that, but i cant say /home/a1206305/directory.php ??

Comment: im getting :  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  from the code